# Type '¨deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install spotify and after failing every time, I try to do `sudo apt update`, but I am greeted with the message

```
Type '¨deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
The list of sources could not be read.
```

does anyone know how to fix/get rid of this?

This is the content of the file:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
¨deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free¨
```

Comment: Show us line one of the sources list. That is where your question says the error is.

Comment: how would i see line one. i have closed terminal and dont see the command anymore

Comment: how would i change it to a ```.```?

Comment: Didn't you post the same question yesterday ignoring all comments to it?

Comment: tried what the comments said and nothing worked

Comment: And then you post exactly the same question and think you will get a better answer? You had better edited your original question telling us what you tried and how it failed so we can help you with that.

Comment: i am new to this i am sorry. the post you shared got me to opening the ```sudoedit``` but i do not know how to delete the ¨ at the beginning

Comment: Please edit your question and add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: In a terminal, run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list`. Then with the mouse, mark the output. Inside the textbox here in the browser, click with middle mouse button.

Comment: i ran the ```cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list``` and it just says ```¨deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free¨```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Fix, remove the `¨` from the file:

Run this,

```bsh
sudo sed -i 's/¨//g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Then you can use `apt` again:

```bsh
sudo apt update
```

---

Why did this issue appear?

Probably you copy-pasted from a tutorial which uses wrong quotes, like

```bsh
echo ¨deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free¨ | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

You need to use always the correct quotes

- Correct: `"` or `'`.  (Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for difference) between these.
- Wrong: `¨` or `“`

Comment: thank you so much, this worked :)